# mac cPanel: "puttygen: error loading unrecognised cipher name"

Tags: ssh, sftp, cpanel

Not sure what's causing this error - trying to convert my private ssh key to .ppk format within cPanel for SFTP via filezilla.

I generated my keys using the following command:

```
 ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

This is the beginning of my key - is this incorrect?

```
-----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
b3BlbnNzaC1rZXktdjEAAAAACmFlczI1Ni1jdHIAAAAGYmNyeXB0AAAAGAAAABDUEyp40b
```

Comment: What PuTTYgen version are you using?

Comment: I'm not using putty gen - just mac terminal to generate SSH keys.

Comment: Well, the only tool for converting keys from/to .ppk format is PuTTYgen, and even your _post title_ says "puttygen"...

Comment: Within cPanel under SSH section, it gives you the option to convert keys to .ppk - going through this process I get the above error. I was wondering if there was an issue with the way I had generated my keys.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The file is correct, but that's the "new" OpenSSH private key format introduced in version 6.5 (made default in 7.8). It is only supported by PuTTY starting with version 0.68.

Because your server tries to perform the conversion using an older PuTTYgen version which doesn't support this format yet, you need to tell `ssh-keygen` to output keys using the older "PEM" format:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -m PEM
```

Or convert an existing key using the "password change" mode:

```
ssh-keygen -p -f ~/my_id_rsa -m PEM
```

Finally, you could also install PuTTY on your own system and use it to convert keys – if you get a sufficiently new version, it'll recognize both ssh-keygen formats:

```
puttygen ~/my_id_rsa -o ~/my_id.ppk -O private
```

See other posts for more detail:

- [Marketing Cloud SSH Key Generation: Inconsistency between Putty and ssh-keygen](https://superuser.com/questions/1484478/marketing-cloud-ssh-key-generation-inconsistency-between-putty-and-ssh-keygen/1484492#1484492)
- [Differences between ssh-keygen private keys and libressl's?](https://superuser.com/questions/1470852/differences-between-ssh-keygen-private-keys-and-libressls/1471273#1471273)

Comment: This was it - thank you very much!